# Getting selected html content in tinymce editor

Tags: get, tinymce

I have created a custom button using this code

```
    setup : function(ed) {
    ed.addButton('Tittle', {
                title : 'Tittle',
                image : './images/T.jpg',
                onclick : function() {
                ed.focus();
            var c = ed.selection.getNode().nodeName;
        if(c!="TITTLE")
        {
             ed.selection.setContent('<tittle>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</tittle>');

        }
        else
        {

        }
}
        });
```

When a user select a text and click on the new button, i want to add a `<title>` tag at beginning  and ending, if `<tittle>` tag is not their.If `<tittle>` tag is already their in the selected text i want to remove the tag

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try

```
selection.getContent({format : 'text'});
```

or

```
selection.getContent({format : 'html'});
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.Selection.getContent

**EDIT:**  To achieve what you want you could do:

```
if(c!="TITTLE") {

  node = ed.selection.getNode();

  with(document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow){
      var newElement = document.createElement("tittle");
      newElement.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;
  }

  node.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, node);

}
else {

  node = ed.selection.getNode();

  with(document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow){
      var newElement = document.createTextNode(node.innerHTML);
  }

  node.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thariama.But it is giving only the text if i select a text with same tag,if i select a textwith 2 different tags it will give the html with content

Comment: hmm, that might be because the selection does only cotain text in the first case, but in the second there are tags in between (inside the selection). does it give you the full html (full tags)?

Comment: ya am getting the full html with the tags

Comment: a not very nice approach could be to widen the selection to get the tags and cut it afterwards

Comment: The tag is  not a html tag i have created the tag.if i select a content with valid html tag then the whole html will coming

Comment: so, the second tag you selected has not been an info tag, but a valid html tag? could you please edit your question and show in detail what you did and what you got

Comment: `if(c!="TITTLE")` part is working.ie if the selected text didnt have `<tittle>` tag i am adding it with `ed.selection.setContent('<tittle>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</tittle>');`.In the else part i want to remove the '<tittle>' tag from the content and replace in the editor.

Comment: so you want to replace it with what?

Comment: I want to remove the `<tittle>` tag.That is content without `<tittle> </tittle>` tag

Comment: It is just like a bold button in tinymce.When i select a text and click on the button (new button) a new tag will added in the selected text.if i again click on the button the tag will remove from the selected text.

Comment: sry, its 'parentNode' nor 'prntNode'

Comment: if i use `parentNode` then it is showing javascript  expession error

Comment: How to get the selected text which i need to convert into link. i m not not mentioning about tags which is selected i need to know how to fetch select text items once i click link icon. help in advance

Comment: @Mohan Ram: sorry, i am not able to undestand what you want to achieve

Comment: How to get attributes of selected node. i had used node = ed.selection.getNode(); to select node object. i need to fetch attributes of this node. how to do that @thariama.

Comment: this is simple, once you got the node you have easy access to them: node.src for the source attribute, node.id for the id-attribute and so on

Answer (score 9):

```
var node = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, %your value, can use node%");
```