# How to replace an element with TinyMCE

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE and i'm creating a new plugin.

I need, in this plugin, to replace something i have selected in the text by an other thing.

With this : `var inst = tinyMCE.activeEditor;` i can have a instance of my editor.

How can i retrieve my selection ? How can i replace my selection by, for example `<span>MYSELECTION</span>` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent',false,'<span>{$selection}</span>');return false;">[Replace selection]</a>
```

EDIT: About retrieving selection see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985524/getting-selected-html-content-in-tinymce-editor) question.

Comment: I need to do that only in javascript. And how i define $selection?

Comment: Then use only "tinyMCE.execCommand(...);" part. $selection, as I understand, is special variable of TinyMCE, which represents current selection. Anyway, see my updated answer, there is another example how to do replace and also get selection.