# Creating TinyMCE toggle button to wrap text in multiple tags but it duplicates content on removal

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I'm attempting to create a toggle button in TinyMCE to wrap the selected text in 2 tags `<aside class="extra">` and `<blockquote class="extra">`. So if I had the following line:

```
Hello, this is just a test. I will select this bit. The rest is not selected.
```

And then highlighted the line "I will select this bit." the result would be:

```
<p>Hello, this is just a test.</p>
<aside class="extra">
<blockquote class="extra">I will select this bit.</blockquote>
</aside>
<p>The rest is not selected.</p>
```

To do this, I have created the button like so:

```
ed.addButton('extraquote', {
    text: false,
    icon: 'blockquote',
    onclick: function () {
        if (ed.selection.getNode().nodeName == "BLOCKQUOTE") {
            ed.selection.setContent(""+$(ed.selection.getNode()).unwrap().html()+"");
        }else{
            ed.selection.setContent('<aside class="extra"><blockquote class="extra">' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</blockquote></aside>');
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine when adding the tags, but when trying to remove them, it adds the text with the tags removed, but keeps the text within the tags there as well. So I get this:

```
<p>Hello, this is just a test. I will select this bit.</p>
<blockquote class="extra">I will select this bit.</blockquote>
<p>The rest is not selected.</p>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ed9dhhvv/1/

Any ideas on how to fix this. Or is there a better way, I was looking at adding custom formats, but as far as I can tell this only works with single tags.

Any help appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: I came across something similar. but I got it working from the example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985524/getting-selected-html-content-in-tinymce-editor and my strikethrough plugin http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/380w7y69/11/